# Pass data from view to controller [LARAVEL]

Tags: php, html, laravel, api, laravel-blade

I have a view which contains mostly **html** and **php** code like shown:

```
echo "<li><span class='caret' ><i class=\"fa fa-location-arrow\" style=\"color:#3399FF\"></i>".$moyenData[$index]['agence']."</span>"; 
echo "<ul class=\"nested\">";
echo "<li><span class=\"caret\" onclick=\"getId($id);   \">".$moyenData[$index]['nom']."</span>";
```

And I want to send the **$id** of the last item (*$moyenData[$index]['nom']*) to the route to call the controller with the **$id** arguments and update a chart on the same page.

Here is my API call:

```
$chronograph = new Client(['base_uri' => 'apiname']); 
  $response = $chronograph->request('GET',$user, [
    'query' => [
        'jour' => $jour, 
        'idv' => $id
    ],
    'auth' => [$username, $password] 
]);
   if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
      $chronoData = json_decode($response->getBody(), true); 
  }
```

So I want to make this call dynamically and not in hard coding like my current code.

To finish, here is my route:

```
Route::get('/', 'MoyenController@getMoyen' )->name('page');
```

Comment: Route::get('/{id?}', 'MoyenController@getMoyen' )->name('page'); you need to make a not required parameter pass to your route

Comment: Thanks for the comment ! I will try it then i will answer here if its work for me !